# Reading a csv and writing it columns into another csv file

Tags: php, file, csv

I'm trying to extract specific columns from a CSV file and trying to store them in another CSV file. My CSV file is tab separated, and some of the column values are in separate lines. When I try to read and write it in another file, it considers them different columns and writes them in different lines. I want the output file to be similar to the information provided in the CSV file. Any help would be appreciated.

When I import the original CSV file, there are some columns which are in different lines coz of `\n\r`. I have tried multiple approaches, but getting similar output. The content in `test.csv` (`\t` is tab):

```
"abc" \t "123" \t "Tom"

"xyz" \t 

"456" \t "Jack"

"mno" \t "789" 

\t "Jim"
```

```php
$file1 = 'try.csv';
$fp=fopen($file1,'w');
if (($handle = fopen("test.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, "\t")) !== FALSE) 
    {
        $num = count($data);
        for ($c=0; $c < 2; $c++) 
        {
            echo $data[$c] . "<br />\n";
        fwrite($fp, $data[$c]);

        }
    fwrite($fp,"\n");
    }
    fclose($fp);
    fclose($handle);
}
```

I want the output to be in this format.

```
"abc" \t "123" 

"xyz" \t  "456"

"mno" \t  "789"
```

Comment: if the `\n\r` are enclosed within quotes as is standard for a CSV this wont be an issue  for example: `abc\t"123\n\rxyz"\t456` would be split into `["abc", "123\n\rxyz", "456"]`  The problem is with the file, trying to read that will be problematic.

Comment: As shown here [Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/0234b755c50d7b944cc01984e98e3d99d50c295c)  This isn't a file, but it works in the same way.  Trying to parse that (if it's missing the quotes to escape the line returns) is going to be a huge mess.  You would be better off splitting the file up by tabs, and then using array_chunk by the number of columns, and hope there are no tabs in the data.

Answer (score 0):

This is the best I can do given the data you provided

```
$string = <<<CSV
"abc" \t "123" \t "Tom"
"xyz" \t
"456" \t "Jack"
"mno" \t "789"
\t "Jim"
CSV;

print_r(array_chunk(array_filter(array_map('trim',preg_split("/\t|\r\n|\n/", $string))), 3));
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => "abc"
            [1] => "123"
            [2] => "Tom"
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => "xyz"
            [1] => "456"
            [2] => "Jack"
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => "mno"
            [1] => "789"
            [2] => "Jim"
        )

)
```

[Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/39e1485ce5ebb5f04f9045e0464c6d64d65f2253)

It's not magic, it's code!

PS. replace `$string` with the contents of your file, and hope there are no tabs in the data.

Comment: Hello @ArtisticPhoenix, Thank you for your answer, but it didn't work for all the data. Suppose if I use this code for this example, it will not give the expected out. Here is the link of the code [link](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/69f11f7b75d42331646f033073706a80b953a31a), but it is only two csv lines with 7 columns. It should create two arrays. Any advice what is the issue?